# Why I'm getting System.InvalidCastException when inserting in mdf database file

Tags: vb.net

I'm just trying to insert some data, I've doubled check my table definition and my variables data type

This is my table definition in mdf database file

```
product_id - int
product_name - varchar(50)
qty_sold - int
date - date
```

and this is my list

```
Dim cart As New List(Of Integer)
Dim product_qty As New List(Of Integer)
```

I'm trying to insert using this code

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To cart.Count - 1

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into sales values('" + cart(i) + "', '" + getName(cart(i)) + "', '" + product_qty(i) + "', '" + datefield.Text + "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

`getName` returns a String so it fits with the `product_name` column while `datefield.Text` returns a date format

and I'm getting this error, some sort of data type error with `Double` thing I think.

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "insert into sales values('" to type 'Double' is not valid.'
```

Comment: Recommend you look into using parameterization to pass in your parameters in your insert.  It prevents SQL Injection attacks, but in your case you can probably also fix your issue at hand.  String concatenation and SQL is often tricky and is a bad practice in general.  `cart(i)` is returning a double, which isn't the same as a `int` is a database.

Comment: `cart(i)` is a double? I've check its elements using messagebox and it displays whole numbers, and I've also insert elements inside `cart` like `cart.Add(4154)`  @TimothyG.

Comment: It is the string concatenation that is wrong: your SQL statement is a string and you are appending values that aren't strings. But this is a terrible way of doing it because of **SQL injection** issues and your code will choke on certain characters like single quotes. Parameterized queries exist for a reason (tons of example on this site), use them and don't bother 'fixing' this code. Bonus for maintaining data integrity: add a **transaction** at the start of your loop and commit at the end or roll back in case of error.

Comment: Use of the `+` operator for string concatenation can cause problems when you use it with things that aren't strings, because then the compiler has to guess what you really want to do.  Sometimes it guesses right, sometimes it guesses wrong.  If string concatenation is what you want, recommend to use the string concatenation operator `&`.  (But really, in this case, don't do that, use a parameterized query to avoid SQL injection issues.)

Comment: If you insist on a string method, you can do something like this, with a Replace on text fields to help protect against sql injection: `cmd.CommandText = $"insert into sales values('{cart(i)}', '{getName(cart(i).replace("'","")})', '{product_qty(i)}', '{datefield.Text}'"`.  Hopefully I didn't miss a parens in there :)

Comment: @technonaut I don't see how that provides protection against injection.  The fundamental problem is that any time you include the values directly in the query, there's a risk of injection.  As a specific example, consider the case where the contents of e.g. `datefield.Text` are something like `'; DROP TABLE students; --`.

Comment: Since you have a list of carts as integers, I assume you are dealing with several carts. There doesn't seem to be any way to connect the carts to the products. You are inserting the same products for each cart. Also the the length of the 2 lists are not necessary the same. You will either be missing some products or get an index out of range exception.

Comment: What is the primary key of the sales table? Is the sales table the one where you showed the names and types of the columns?

Comment: Parallel list are not the way to go. Create classes for you data and make your lists of the class type.

Comment: @Craig That's true, and I agree it's best not to take this approach, but I wasn't trying to provide the wholly coded solution but rather just illustrate that with some careful text manipulation, it is possible to "code out" certain types of abuse situations.  Parameterized queries are the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the `date` column to `SaleDate`. You will avoid extra work trying to except the name date as a reserved word or type in .net. Always list the fields you are inserting. Otherwise your inserts are positional. DBAs have been known to add fields and you may have missed the memo.

I created 2 classes to hold your data. Fill you class' instances with your data from the user interface or wherever. Add the instances to the lists.

Then pass the lists to the `InsertSales` method.

The the Connection, Command, and ParametersCollection are created only once outside the loops. The connection is opened outside the loop. Only the values of the values of the parameters change inside the loops. The command is executed on each iteration of the inner loop.

```
Public Class Cart
    Public CartDate As Date
    Public CartContents As New List(Of ProductSale)
End Class

Public Class ProductSale
    Public ProcuctID As Integer
    Public ProductName As String
    Public QuantitySold As Integer
End Class

Private Carts As New List(Of Cart)

Private Products As New List(Of ProductSale)

Private Sub InsertSales(CartList As List(Of Cart), ProductList As List(Of ProductSale))
    Dim sql = "insert into sales (product_id, product_name, qty_sold, saledate) values (@ProductId, @ProductName, @QuantitySold, @DateSold)"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProcuctID", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuanitySold", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateSold", SqlDbType.Date)
        con.Open()
        For Each c As Cart In CartList
            cmd.Parameters("@DateSold").Value = c.CartDate
            For Each p As ProductSale In c.CartContents
                cmd.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = p.ProcuctID
                cmd.Parameters("@ProductName").Value = p.ProductName
                cmd.Parameters("@QuantitySold").Value = p.QuantitySold
            Next
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

BTW, it is redundant to have columns for both product id and product name. I presume there is a Products table with product Id as the primary key and a column for product name. You are storing the same data twice. Suppose they change the product name. You would have to do a huge update.