# My Update SQL parameter only update the 1st row of my database table

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update `product_qty` inside my mdf file database based on values given in my two list of Integers, I basically just want to loop inside of my list to gather `IDs` and a collection of quantities inside `product_qty()` list. I just want to subtract quantites here

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To cart.Count - 1
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE product SET product_qty= product_qty - @qty WHERE product_id= @id"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", product_qty(i))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cart(i))
        i = i + 1
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
```

This is my list data type filled with `IDs` and `quantities`

```
Dim cart As New List(Of Integer)
Dim product_qty As New List(Of Integer)
```

Comment: Not really 100% sure what the question is here.  Are you asking how to update the value of the parameters?

Comment: yes @Hursey I mean there is something wrong with my placement of codes, I just don't know where.

Comment: my iterator never increments It just updates the zeroth index of `cart(i)` @Hursey

Comment: Drop the i = i +1.  Don't need that.  All handled in the for loop.  Few other things in there that can get tidied up but strt with that

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The variable name '@qty' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.'
This error came from `executeNonQuery` @Hursey when I remove that `i=i+1`

Comment: See my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact syntax is probably a little off as I'm doing this from memory, but concept is what I'm going for so should be enough to get you going in the right direction with a little research.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE product SET product_qty= product_qty - @qty WHERE product_id= @id"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Int32)
cmd.Parameters.Add(("@id", SqlDbType.Int32)
For i As Integer = 0 To cart.Count - 1
    cmd.Parameters("@id").value = cart(1)
    cmd.Parameters("@qty").value = product_qty(i)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Key thing is, you setup the sql command outside the loop first, then withing the loop all you need to do is update the value of the pre-existing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would not have the linq code to get `ShorterList` in the database code but it is unpleasant (maybe impossible) to use anonymous types outside the method where they are created.

The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that the connection is closed and disposed and the command is disposed. Using should be used with any type that exposes a `.Dispose` method.

The rest is the same as my answer to [Why I'm getting System.InvalidCastException when inserting in mdf database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891992/why-im-getting-system-invalidcastexception-when-inserting-in-mdf-database-file)

```
Public Class Cart
    Public CartDate As Date
    Public CartContents As New List(Of ProductSale)
End Class
Public Class ProductSale
    Public ProcuctID As Integer
    Public ProductName As String
    Public QuantitySold As Integer
End Class

Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Carts As New List(Of Cart)

Private Products As New List(Of ProductSale)


Private Sub UpdateInventory(Products As List(Of ProductSale))
    Dim ShorterList = (From p In Products
                       Group By ID = p.ProcuctID
                          Into g = Group, Sum(p.QuantitySold)
                       Select ID, Sum).ToList
    'To optimize the Update use Group By and sum on the resultant list so each product is only updated once.
    Dim sql = "UPDATE product SET product_qty= product_qty - @Quantity WHERE product_id= @Id"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int)
        con.Open()
        For Each a In ShorterList
            cmd.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = a.Sum
            cmd.Parameters("@Id").Value = a.ID
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of ProductSale)
    'Combine all the carts contents to a single list
    For Each c As Cart In Carts
        lst.AddRange(c.CartContents)
    Next
    UpdateInventory(lst)
End Sub
```