# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: while inserting data to mdf database file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Im getting this error while inserting data to my mdf database file

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@qtysold' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.'
```

This is my code for `order` function

```
Function order(ByVal cart As List(Of Integer), ByVal product_qty As List(Of Integer))
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()

    End If
    con.Open()

 
    'INSERT INTO PRODUCT TABLE
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE product SET product_qty= product_qty - @qty WHERE product_id= @id"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
    For i As Integer = 0 To cart.Count - 1
        cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = cart(i)
        cmd.Parameters("@qty").Value = product_qty(i)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

    'INSERT INTO SALES TABLE
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sales VALUES (@id, @productname, @qtysold, @date)"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@productname", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@qtysold", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date)
    For i As Integer = 0 To cart.Count - 1
        cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = cart(i)
        cmd.Parameters("@productname").Value = getName(cart(i))
        cmd.Parameters("@qtysold").Value = product_qty(i)
        cmd.Parameters("@date").Value = datefield.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

    cart.Clear()
    product_qty.Clear()

    refresh()


End Function
```

THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE

```
cmd.Parameters("@qtysold").Value = product_qty(i)
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the line `cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date)`, then check if 'Results view' in 'cmd.Parameters' contains '@qtysold' after the program runs.

Comment: I warned you about this 2 questions ago in comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891992/why-im-getting-system-invalidcastexception-when-inserting-in-mdf-database-file

Comment: You are assuming that `cart` is the same length as `product_qty`.  I would think that a customer could put any number of products in their cart and this would have nothing to do with how many carts are involved.

Answer (score 1):

That seems an odd exception in that situation as the code looks OK to me but it's wrong even if it did work. Don't add the parameters and then get them back by name over and over. The `Add` method you're calling returns the `SqlParameter` object added so assign it to a variable and then use that:

```vb
Dim idParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
Dim productionNameParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@productname", SqlDbType.VarChar)
Dim qtySoldParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@qtysold", SqlDbType.Int)
Dim dateParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date)

For i As Integer = 0 To cart.Count - 1
    idParameter.Value = cart(i)
    productionNameParameter.Value = getName(cart(i))
    qtySoldParameter.Value = product_qty(i)
    dateParameter.Value = datefield.Text

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

NEVER use the same complex expression over and over. ALWAYS use it once and assign the result to a variable, then use that variable over and over. In this case, you don't even have to use the complex expression once, because you already had the object but just ignored it.